# Which jar file contains RowCounter class for Hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am at my wits end.  I can't find which jar file contains these two classes:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter.RowCounterMapper;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
```

I've tried:

- looking it up on findjar.com
- used my GoogleFu
- praying to computer gods
- manually tried several of the jars from cloudera via maven (for RowCounter).

Eclipse still says those import lines are not resolved.

How do I find the jar file that contains these classes or any class for that matter that I need for my program to compile?

Thanks in advance.  I'm ready to ram my head into the wall.

Comment: ```org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter.RowCounterMapper``` is not public, so you couldn't import like that. ```org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter``` belongs to org.apache.hbase/hbase-server

Comment: @sel-fish, the code on this link makes that call to RowCounterMapper.  I'm just trying to copy them to try to use RowCounter.  Too bad I can't get it to work  =(  http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=pbase-master/hbase-server/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TestRowCounter.java

Comment: the reason that code can work is that this test runs in the same package as ```org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter.RowCounterMapper```, so you just want to run ```RowCounter``` ?

Comment: @sel-fish, yes, I want to run RowCounter but I can't find any code examples online.  this was the only example i could find; another case of my poor google-fu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RowCounterMapper`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase-server/1.1.1/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/RowCounter.java#RowCounter) is in HBase Server. Maven dependency:

`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>`

[`Category`](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12) is in Junit 4. Maven dependency:

`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>`

I have also added links to GrepCode.

Comment: thx @vsync.  i was using junit 3.8 by default from maven/eclipse, which you pointed out didn't have that feature.  arrrg

Answer (score 2):

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter.RowCounterMapper- [hbase jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase)

org.junit.experimental.categories.Category [junit jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.8.1)

Answer (score 1):

Base on the comments, @Classified wants a example to run `RowCounter`.
[Here](https://github.com/sel-fish/hbase-experiments/blob/master/src/test/java/com/mogujie/mst/hbase/mapreduce/RowCounterTest.java) is a unittest I wrote which I think could be an exmaple.

```
Job job = RowCounter.createSubmittableJob(HBaseConfiguration.create(), new String[]{"table"});
job.waitForCompletion(true);
Counters counters = job.getCounters();
GenericCounter genericCounter = (GenericCounter) counters.findCounter(
                    "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter$RowCounterMapper$Counters",
                    "ROWS");
genericCounter.getValue();
```

`genericCounter.getValue()` is the row count of `"table"`.